# MATLAB error at line with ode45

Tags: matlab, ode45

Im trying to get matlab to display a graph of prey vs predetor

```
function [ output_args ] = Untitled( input_args )

    options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'NonNegative', [1 2]);

    [t,x] = ode45('lotka_volterra', [0 30], [2 1], options);

    plot(t,x);
    legend('prey', 'predators');

end


function dxdt = lotka_volterra(t,x)

    a     = 1.2;
    b     = 0.6;
    d     = 0.3;
    gamma = 0.8;

    dxdt    = [0;0];
    dxdt(1) = a * x(1) - b * x(1) * x(2);
    dxdt(2) = d * x(1) * x(2) - gamma * x(2);

end
```

The point is to display the dynamic relationship between the populations of two species living in the same environment.

The two derivatives(dxdt(1) and dxdt(2)) model the rate of change of each population

Im tryint to use the Runge-Kutta method of Integration to get the plot of the population vs time, of the two species

The error just says:

```
Error in Untitled (line 3)
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) lotka_volterra, [0 30], [2 1]);
```

Im very stumped any help would be great

Comment: Are you sure that's what the *entire* error says?

Comment: Oh yes sorry there's more. First it said unrecognised double  'lotka_volterra', then I got rid of the quotes, it said not enough arguments, then adding arguments it says 
Attempted to access x(2); index out of bounds because numel(x)=1.

Error in trial>lotka_volterra (line 16)
dxdt(1) = a * x(1) - b * x(1) * x(2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the function handle:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@lotka_volterra, [0 30], [2;1], options);
```

or, slower but maybe clearer:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) lotka_volterra(t,x), [0 30], [2;1], options);
```

Comment: @GeorgeDziouba Glad that I could help.